# Struggling with pagination implementation

Tags: php

I've partially developed my pagination implementation, but I have an issue.

I want the pagination to look like this:

```
Page 3 | Page 4 | Page 5
```

The middle link in the pagination is the currently selected page. If the page is 0 the currently selected page is the first link. If the page is not 0 the currently selected page is the second link. If the page is the last page the currently selected page is the 3rd link.

So far my implementation highlights the current page, but does not make the current page the center link. Also, when it gets to the last page, it adds 2 additional pages to the pagination that don't exist.

```
<?php for($i=0; $i <= $pages && $i < 3; $i++) : ?>
    <li <?php echo ($page == $i + $page) ? 'class="current-page"' : '' ?>><a href="category.php?category=<?php echo $category->category ?>&page=<?php echo $page + $i ?>"><?php echo $page + $i ?></a></li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Any advice?

Comment: `($page == $i + $page)`  <-- This is only, and always, true when `$i == 0`.

Comment: Can you give a value for `$pages`?  Would it be 3, or 5 in your example?

Comment: Yes, the pages would be numbered from 0 ... n but I used 3 - 5 as an examples.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand your question, this gives the right output.

```
<?php
$page = 3;
$pages = 5;
$category = 'abc';
?>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= $pages && $i < 3; $i++) : ?>
<li<?php echo ($i == 1) ? ' class="current-page"' : '' ?>>
    <a href="category.php?category=<?php echo $category ?>&page=<?php echo $page + $i ?>"><?php echo $page + $i ?></a>
</li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

The output would be...

```
<li>
    <a href="category.php?category=abc&page=3">3</a>
</li>
<li class="current-page">
    <a href="category.php?category=abc&page=4">4</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="category.php?category=abc&page=5">5</a>
</li>
```

I simplified `$category->category` to `$category` for testing.  Make sure to change that back in your code.

The reason for `($i == 1)` instead of `($page == $i + $page)` is in the data set `0, 1, 2` (your values for `$1`) **1** is the center.  If that's a simplified version, you'll have to do some more math, for example, `number of items / 2 rounded down` should give the center.

Hope that helps.  If not, add some more information and I'll update my answer.